# change key move event to mouse click and move c#

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2012, mouse

Ok so far i have

```
private void UserControl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Up)
            this.Pin.Move(Direction.Up);
        if (e.Key == Key.Down)
            this.Pin.Move(Direction.Down);
        if (e.Key == Key.Left)
            this.Pin.Move(Direction.Left);
        if (e.Key == Key.Right)
            this.Pin.Move(Direction.Right);
    }
```

It is great, i can move my object with up down left and right. I would like to control it with my souse cursor though. any idea how i would do this.
Im not good at this and have just started some pointers will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you want to override the [OnMouseMove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.onmousemove%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method for your UserControl. You can then look at the MouseEventArgs which you get from that handler and use the GetPosition method to get the mouse co-ordinate.

If you stored this point in a local varaible somewhere, the after the first mouse move you could compare it and move it in the appropriate direction. An example bit of code might be

```
private Point prev;

private void UserControl_OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point p = e.GetPosition();
    if(prev == null)
       prev = p;

    if(p.Y > prev.Y) 
         this.Pin.Move(Direction.Up);
    else if(p.Y < prev.Y) 
          this.Pin.Move(Direction.Down);
    etc. 
    prev = p;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is not the right logic...how about the p.Y, and moving in any direction

Comment: Thank you for your information, I will accept one of these answerers im just going through both of them trying to understand them and get them to work.

Comment: With some alterations got this to work in the end, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The following might help you with modification to fit your implementation

```
private bool _isMouseDown;

  private void UserControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_isMouseDown)
            {
                this.Pin.Location = new Point(e.X,e.Y);
            }
        }

        private void UserControl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            _isMouseDown = true;
        }
        private void UserControl_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            _isMouseDown = false;
        }
```

Comment: I know this will work as i can read the logic, thank you. I will accept answer once i have got the code working in my program.